# Is there a reason why C doesn't let me write to this file?

Tags: c, windows, file, error-handling, fopen

I am new to C, and I am trying to get the hang of file handling. I have tried writing to this file but its not working, and I am not sure why it doesn't work, could someone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("out.txt","w+");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR");
        exit(-1);
    }
    char test[] = "HELLO";
    fprintf (f, "%s", test);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
    
    
}
```

I keep getting the "ERROR" message when I check if the file has been opened :/

Comment: Either a permissions problem in the current working directory, such that you are not allowed to create new files or write to existing ones, or the file exists but is currently locked for write because it's open in another process.  Show exactly how you are running this program.

Answer (score 5):

Replace rather useless

```c
printf("ERROR");
```

with

```c
perror("fopen");
```

C doesn't require `fopen` to set `errno` (which is used by `perror`), but POSIX does, and the usual compilers for Linux and Windows set it.

---

The error is almost surely going to be EPERM ("Permission denied"). That error means one of the following:

- you don't have permission to access that directory,
- you don't have permission to write to that directory (if the file doesn't exist),
- you don't have permission to read that directory (if the file exists),
- you don't have permission to modify the file (if the file exists), or
- the file is locked by another program (if the file exists).

Well, other causes are possible, but so unlikely I don't know what they would be.

Your program attempts to create or modify a file in the current directory. Note that the current directory is not necessarily the directory in which the executable is located. You're probably trying to write to the wrong directory accidentally.

Comment: Note that ISO C does not require that `errno` be set by `fopen` on failure. This is a requirement of POSIX. Therefore, `perror` is not guaranteed to provide a meaningful error message. It may simply print something like `"No Error"`, which would be misleading. For this reason, writing `printf("ERROR");` is the proper portable way to report a failure of the function `fopen`. However, I am still upvoting the answer, because there there is no better solution and there is a high probability that OP is using a platform on which `fopen` does set `errno` on failure.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel k, didn't know that. But it still prints what errors even if what follows is junk.

Comment: Yes, in your example, it will print something like `fopen: Success` or `fopen: No Error`. Although this output is very misleading, if the programmer is aware of this, then it does still provide helpful debugging information. In the ideal case, a portable application should probably set `errno` to `0` before the `fopen` function call and, in case `fopen` returns `NULL`, it should verify that `errno != 0` before calling `perror`. Otherwise, it should provide its own error message.

Comment: As a matter of QoI, an implementation in which `fopen` doesn't set `errno` on failure is not fit for purpose. In the unlikely event you find one, you should file a bug report.

Comment: @ikegami It should properly be perror("out.txt"). I have lost count of the times the problem turned out to be that the filename wasn't what the programmer thought it was.

Comment: @zwol should have both. `die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n")` is what I use in Perl, `$!` being errno.

Comment: @ikegami I think you misunderstand -- I know it's not an ISO C requirement for `fopen` to set `errno`, but I am saying that `fopen` not setting `errno` _is an implementation bug_, even on a system that claims ISO C but not POSIX conformance. No excuses will be accepted.

Comment: @zwol, I did indeed completely misread. Deleted comment.

Comment: I have used perror and I am getting the message "ERROR : Permission denied". How do I fix this? BTW im using Visual studio to code this

Comment: @rperager: Since you say that you are using Microsoft Visual Studio (not Microsoft Visual Studio Code, which is a different product), I assume that you are using Microsoft Windows. Does the file already exist in the current directory of your program? You can use the function [`_getcwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getcwd-wgetcwd?view=msvc-160) to obtain it (you must `#include <direct.h>`). If not, are you able to create a file `"out.txt"` in the working directory of your program by hand (without using your program)?

Comment: @rperager: If the file already exists, is the file maybe already opened by another program? Do you maybe have it open in a text editor/viewer?

Comment: Note that the current directory is not necessarily the directory in which the executable is located. The error means one of the following: 1) you don't have permission to access that directory (if the file exists), 2) you don't have permission to write to that directory (if the file doesn't exist), 3) you don't have permission to read that directory (if the file exists), 4) you don't have permission to modify the file (if the file exists), or 5) the file is locked by another program (if the file exists).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, my bad, I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Code, I was unaware that they were 2 separate products.

Comment: @rperager: Oh, then my assumption that you are using Microsoft Windows was also incorrect? Or are you using that operating system? Since file/directory permissions are very operating-system specific, it is important to know your operating system in order to answer your question.

Comment: @ikegami How would one go about gaining permission? I dont see why I dont have permission. I have tried reading from a text file I created and it worked, but I cant seem to write to a file

Comment: @rperager: The question in your previous comment cannot be answered until you specify your operating system. Note that I have tagged your question with the "windows" tag because you specified that you were using Visual Studio, but I am not sure if that information was correct, because you now stated that you are using Visual Studio Code instead.

Comment: This is now the second question you've asked in the comments. Comments aren't for new questions. That's on top of the complete lack of information provided in the question. This happens a lot with questions in the comments, and it's a huge reason that's why it's not appropriate to ask them there.

Comment: Anyway, it's very likely the solution to not having permissions is to use a directory to which you do have permissions rather than adding permissions. But who knows. Again, complete lack of info.

Comment: @ikegami: It is appropriate to settle the issue about the operating system though, because your answer seems to be based on the assumption that OP is using Microsoft Windows, which, for the reasons stated in my comments above, may have been a false assumption.

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel, No, it doesn't. If anything, I assumed Linux. My answer is just as true on Linux and I think BSDs incl Macs. (Locking being a reason only applies to Windows, though.)

Comment: @ikegami, I am new to stackOverflow, sorry about the asking questions within the comments section, I am using Windows OS